# Preferred approach on upgrading Magento Community 2.1 to 2.4

Tags: magento2, upgrade, version-upgrade

What's your approach to upgrading the Magento Community version from `2.1` to `2.4`?

1. Incremental approach (`2.1` > `2.2` > `2.3` > `2.4`)
2. Direct upgrade from `2.1` to `2.4`

As this involves infrastructural upgrades and module/package addition/upgrades, what's your take on approach and why?

Answer (score 1):

Of course, Upgrade Directly **2.1** to **2.4**

If you upgrade from **2.1 to 2.2 to 2.3 to 2.4** that is meaning less process. because the end result will be same.

*So, Please Upgrade to 2.4 Directly.*

Answer (score 1):

Definitely, You can upgrade directly from 2.1.18 to 2.4. It is working. Recently I have **upgraded Magento version 2.1.18 to 2.4.3** without any breaking.
Thanks

Comment: Good to know. What was your approach to upgrading?

Comment: Thanks @MagePsycho, first of all, I installed the latest Magento, replace old db with fresh magento in env.php file and run all commands and fix errors. It is easy way to upgrade.